# Why in Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1, the results returned using the same `last` command can be alternated?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When using `last` function to query results in Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1, the actually returned data is not the latest one, and with the same query statement using `last`, the results are returned alternately (which should not be the case, should return the same result for one time series). Has anyone encountered the same problem and know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can update Apache IoTDB to the latest version (version 1.2 and above). Similar bugs should already be fixed.